# What type of file output does the libav decode have?

Tags: decode, libav

I use this function to decode a .wave file https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/decode__audio_8c_source.html. if I call the function, what type should be the output file (extension of decoded data).

Answer (score 0):

It’s doesn’t have a file extension,  It’s just a raw memory buffer of audio samples. The `format` field in the codec context has an enum describing the format. It could be almost anything from signed/unsigned, 8/16 bits per sample or even a float per sample, or . It may also be planar, meaning each channel has its own memory buffer in the `data` field. The complete list is here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavu__sampfmts.html#gaf9a51ca15301871723577c730b5865c5